# How to cast an object to a generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a Mock list like this.

```cs
var MockList = new List<Mock>() {
    new Mock<IBikeRepository>(MockBehavior.Strict),
    new Mock<IGreeterService>(MockBehavior.Strict)
};
```

Now I get back one object like this.

```cs
var greeterServiceMock = this.MockList
.FirstOrDefault(mock => typeof(Mock<IGreeterService>) == mock.GetType());
```

Since `MockList` is of the type `List<Mock>`, the object that I pulled out from the list `this.MockList` is of the type `Mock`. But I can see the runtime type is `Mock<IGreeterService>`

Now I have to cast it to `Mock<IGreeterService>`

Is there a way here?

## Edit

I think I got it.

```
var t = (Mock<IGreeterService>)greeterServiceMock!;
```

The **!** at the end was the key. It was giving error without it and so I had to put the question here.

Comment: If you are using the `!` operator there, you are telling the compiler that you are certain that it won't be null.  If you are certain it won't be null, it would be more idiomatic to just use `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`, and then you won't need the `!`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you still need to cast is that `FirstOrDefault` will return a reference of the type of the list. You can filter ans cast at the same time by using `OfType`:

```
this.MockList.OfType<Mock<IGreeterService>>().FirstOrDefault();
```